# Custom URL Param for Rails REST API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a **Customers controller** to handle the requests for **Customer resource which belongs to Company**. I want to be able to **GET customers** both, either by **customer_id** or **phone_number**.
The default **GET** method can only get me access to the **customer_id** and the **company_id**.
How should I modify my **routes** to be able to manage this?

Here's the code for my **Customers Controller**

```
class Api::V1::CustomersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    customer_id = params[:id]
    mobile_number = params[:mobile_number]
    if mobile_number
      customer = Customer.find(mobile_number)
      render json: customer, status: 201
    else
      if customer_id
        customer = Customer.find(customer_id)
        render json: customer, status: 201
      else
        render json: { errors: "Customer ID and Phone Number is NULL" }, status: 422
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**The routes.rb file :**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  # API routes path
  get '/', :to => redirect('/index.html')
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:show, :create, :update, :index]
      resources :sessions, only:[:create, :destroy]
      resources :companies, only:[:create, :destroy] do
        resources :products
        resources :customers do
          resources :invoices
        end
        resources :categories do
          resources :products
        end
      end
      resources :products, only:[:create, :destroy]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How will be the sample response for customers will be? Can you show us?

Comment: {
    "id": 1,
    "company_id": 1,
    "name": "john doe",
    "isActive": true,
    "created_at": "2j017-06-17T08:20:26.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-17T08:20:26.000Z",
    "mobile": 0,
    "address": "",
    "pan_number": null,
    "tin_number": null,
    "party_name": ""
}

Comment: It'll be the JSON response containing the customer details

Comment: Ok. so what is the issue you are having with the controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default GET method can only get me access to the customer_id and
>   the company_id.

Actually it defines the name of the parameter but you can use it anyway you want; in your case you could search using `params[:id]` in both `id` and `mobile_number`, for example:

```
class Api::V1::CustomersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    customer = Customer.find_by(mobile_number: params[:id])

    if customer.empty?
      customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    end

    if customer.present?
      render json: customer, status: 201
    else
      render json: { errors: "Customer ID and Phone Number is NULL" }, status: 422
    end
  end
end
```

So you could use either an `id` or `mobile_number` in the api call; for example, using `id`:

```
api/v1/companies/customer/1
```

Or, using `mobile_number`:

```
api/v1/companies/customer/55555555
```

The only issue here will be that, if the `id` is a number and `mobile_number` has only digits, then you could eventually have a `params[:id]` that will find a `Customer` with both `id` and `mobile_number`; in which it will return the `Customer` found by `mobile_number`.

If this represents a problem, then you could receive named parameters (by query string) and a similar setup<sup>1</sup> as currently have on your controller, just fix how you query `Customer` when using `mobile_number`:

```
class Api::V1::CustomersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def show
    customer_id = params[:id]
    mobile_number = params[:mobile_number]

    if mobile_number
      customer = Customer.find_by(mobile_number: mobile_number)
    else
      customer = Customer.find(customer_id)
    end

    if customer.present?
      render json: customer, status: 201
    else
      render json: { errors: "Customer ID and Phone Number is NULL" }, status: 422
    end
  end
end
```

Then you will just need to modify your routes to change `get` default for `customers`:

```
resources :customers, except: [:show] do
  resources :invoices
  get '/customer', to: `customer#show'
end
```

And the api call should specify what parameter is being called; for example, asking for `id`:

```
api/v1/companies/customer?id=1
```

Asking for `mobile_number`:

```
api/v1/companies/customer?mobile_number=55555555
```

<sup>1</sup> *I changed the logic a bit to account for valid `id` or `mobile_number` provided as parameters but do not exist on `customers` table.*